# Receive Date including timezone offset as String and convert to a different format using that timezone

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I am receiving from my clients a String like these in this format

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX:

2021-02-04T15:31:22.265-05:00
2021-02-04T15:31:22.265+00:00
2021-02-04T15:31:22.265-06:00
```

and i need to convert them to a new format:

```
MMMM dd, yyyy - HH:mm a z (where z is the three character abbreviation for the timezone. Ex. EST)

February 02, 2021 - 15:31 PM EST
February 02, 2021 - 15:31 PM UTC
February 02, 2021 - 15:31 PM CST
```

Normally i would do something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat inDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
        SimpleDateFormat outDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy - HH:mm a z")
        Date date = inDateFormat.parse("2021-02-04T15:31:22.265-05:00");
        String convertedTime = outDateFormat.format(date) // February 02, 2021 - 15:31 PM EST
```

But i then realized that it was only printing EST because thats where I am. But if a user were to be in another timezone and use this it would become their time but EST would still be on the end. Such as if they send 2021-02-04T15:31:22.265+00:00 then it would return February 02, 2021 - 15:31 PM EST which is 5 hours in the past for them.

**So how can i take a string that includes the offset and simply turn it into a string in a different format from the same offset?** I would expect the outcome of someone from UTC sending 2021-02-04T15:31:22.265+00:00 to be February 02, 2021 - 15:31 PM UTC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way by which I can get TimeZone value using time stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60790342/is-there-any-way-by-which-i-can-get-timezone-value-using-time-stamp)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can derive a timezone offset from a timezone ID but not the other way round i.e. you can not derive a timezone ID using a timezone offset; because the same timezone offset can be applicable for many timezone IDs e.g.

The following code is absolutely valid

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]");
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, uuuu - HH:mm a XXX");
        System.out.println(zdt.format(dtfOutput));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
December 03, 2007 - 10:15 am +01:00
```

whereas the following code will throw exception:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-02-04T15:31:22.265-05:00");
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, uuuu - HH:mm a z");
        System.out.println(odt.format(dtfOutput));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to extract ZoneId from temporal 2021-02-04T15:31:22.265-05:00
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext.getValue(DateTimePrintContext.java:289)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$ZoneTextPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:4083)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2343)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.formatTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:1848)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(DateTimeFormatter.java:1822)
    at java.base/java.time.OffsetDateTime.format(OffsetDateTime.java:1681)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Note that the date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: yeah I had a hunch that I would end up not knowing the exact timezone the client was in due to the >1 options I'd end up with. Bummer! I'll be reading up on the newer methods of dealing with dates in general. Specifically OffsetDateTime. Thank you!